# How to create a column which displays data type of each value in a column which has an 'object' datatype

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Below is a simplified version of the df in question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col_1':[1,2,'Three',4,1.2,'_33']})

df

    col_1
0   1
1   2
2   Three
3   4
4   1.2
5   _33

df.dtypes
col_1     object
dtypes    object
dtype: object
```

I want to create a new column which shows the data type for each value in `col_1`.

INTENDED DF:

```
    col_1   dtypes
0   1       int
1   2       int
2   Three   string
3   4       int
4   1.2     float
5   _33     string
```

Answer (score 2):

Generate `type` to new column:

```
df['types'] = df['col_1'].apply(type)
print (df)
   col_1            types
0      1    <class 'int'>
1      2    <class 'int'>
2  Three    <class 'str'>
3      4    <class 'int'>
4    1.2  <class 'float'>
5    _33    <class 'str'>
```

If need class name use lambda function:

```
df['types'] = df['col_1'].apply(lambda x: type(x).__name__)
print (df)

   col_1  types
0      1    int
1      2    int
2  Three    str
3      4    int
4    1.2  float
5    _33    str
```